# how to get currently opened windows directory?

Tags: java

do we have any option to retrieve the current opened window directory through java code.

I have a `thread`, that needs to listen when ever user opening any directory/folder in windows and it should return the absolute path of the same.

Comment: So you're looking for a program that will monitor windows explorer?

Comment: hi sam... if i opened any directory/folder for example(c:\temp\movie).. the thread need to listen and return the path which user currently opened.here it should return(c:\temp\movie)

Comment: yes sam.. it should locate the address from windows explorer.